# Calling a function within Promise.catch is undefined

Tags: javascript

Attempting to call a function from within a Promise.catch to handle for an error situation, but I'm not sure how to structure it to avoid getting an undefined reference

The goal is call an async login() function and if the password is invalid display a message to the user

```
// Log in user
login(email, password){
//send login request to firebase
  this.af.auth.login(
    {
      email: email,
      password: password
    },
    {
      provider: AuthProviders.Password,
      method: AuthMethods.Password,
    }
  ).then(function(){
    console.log('Success');
  })
  .catch(function(error){
    this.showLoginErrorWindow(error);
  );
}

// Display error message to user 
// ** This function never gets called **
showLoginErrorWindow(message){
    console.log('message: ' + message);
    this.loginErrorMessage = 'Invalid email or password';
    this.showLoginError = true;    //Angular
}
```

Gives me the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'showLoginErrorWindow' of null
```

Comment: Promise is a javascript async method, and you are trying to use `this` in the javascript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: post all your code, no way to know what `this` refers to in your example

Comment: log `this` and check what is inside.

Comment: Scoping issue using `this`. Turn it into an arrow function

Answer (score 2):

Just add `current` to the method and use it as you want. thats a link hack i do everytime.

```
// Log in user
login(email, password){
//send login request to firebase
var current = this;
  this.af.auth.login(
    {
      email: email,
      password: password
    },
    {
      provider: AuthProviders.Password,
      method: AuthMethods.Password,
    }
  ).then(function(){
    console.log('Success');
  })
  .catch(function(error){
    current.showLoginErrorWindow(error);
  );
}

// Display error message to user 
// ** This function never gets called **
showLoginErrorWindow(message){
    console.log('message: ' + message);
    this.loginErrorMessage = 'Invalid email or password';
    this.showLoginError = true;    //Angular
}
```

This is probably me doing it, if i am wrong please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I recently got stuck with a similar kind of problem with firebase API. I was able to solve it by using the arrow function rather than the normal ones in the catch function something like:

```
login(email, password){
  //send login request to firebase
  var current = this;
  this.af.auth.login(
    {
      email: email,
      password: password
    },
    {
      provider: AuthProviders.Password,
      method: AuthMethods.Password,
    }
  ).then(function(){
    console.log('Success');
  })
  .catch((error)=>{
    current.showLoginErrorWindow(error);
  );
}
```